# Changing compiler flags on the fly in a CMake project

Tags: cmake

I've got a large cmake project which is currently completely built for production; the default gcc flags options are something like  `-fpic -s -O3`.

What is the easiest way to recompile a small part of my project with different gcc flags?

But the only way I know how to accomplish this is by regenerating my makefiles with cmake, building the subproject, and regenerating the makefiles again.

```
$ cmake ../ -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS="-fpic -g"
$ make subproject
$ cmake ../ -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS="-fpic -s -O3"
```

I'd like to be able to leave cmake out of it, and do something like this:

```
$ make C_FLAGS="-fpic -g" subproject
```

Comment: Why don't simply use 2 build directories Release and Debug?

Comment: I suppose there's nothing against doing that.. does that mean what I'm asking is impossible?

Answer (score 2):

You can set the compile flags on a per-target basis using the [`COMPILE_FLAGS` target property](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#prop_tgt%3aCOMPILE_FLAGS).

Note that this cannot be set directly from the command line, so you will have to change your CMakeLists.txt. You can however include an [option](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command%3aoption) that allows switching this from the command line:

```
add_library(subproject...)

set_property(TARGET subproject PROPERTY COMPILE_FLAGS "-fpic")
option(BUILD_SUBPROJECT_WITH_O3 Toggles optimizations for the subproject" OFF)
if(BUILD_SUBPROJECT_WITH_O3)
    set_property(TARGET subproject PROPERTY APPEND COMPILE_FLAGS "-s" "-O3")
else()
    set_property(TARGET subproject PROPERTY APPEND COMPILE_FLAGS "-g")
endif()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to add a flag for building one file (in my case, I'm adding -H to track down a header file), you can do this:

```
make VERBOSE=1
```

Then, copy the call to the compiler, add your flag, and call the compiler directly from the shell instead of going through make.  My example, notice the -H on the end:

```
arm-none-eabi-g++  -DARM_MATH_DSP -DARM_MATH_LOOPUNROLL -DCPU_CORTEX_M55=1 -DPLATFORM_HAL=1 -DPRJ_DES_STR="\"ARM ML Embedded Evaluation Kit for MPS3 FPGA and FastModel\"" -DPRJ_VER_STR=\"21.5\" -I/home/ubuntu/contents/ml-embedded-evaluation-kit/dependencies/core-software/drivers/timing_adapter/include -I/home/ubuntu/contents/ml-embedded-evaluation-kit/source -I/home/ubuntu/contents/ml-embedded-evaluation-kit/source/tflite-model -I/home/ubuntu/contents/ml-embedded-evaluation-kit/source/model-parameters -I/home/ubuntu/contents/ml-embedded-evaluation-kit/source/application/hal/include -I/home/ubuntu/contents/ml-embedded-evaluation-kit/source/application/hal/platforms/bare-metal/bsp/cmsis-device/include -I/home/ubuntu/contents/ml-embedded-evaluation-kit/source/application/hal/platforms/bare-metal/bsp/include -I/home/ubuntu/contents/ml-embedded-evaluation-kit/source/application/hal/platforms/bare-metal/bsp/bsp-core/include -I/home/ubuntu/contents/ml-embedded-evaluation-kit/source/application/hal/platforms/bare-metal/bsp/bsp-packs/mps3/include -I/home/ubuntu/contents/ml-embedded-evaluation-kit/source/application/hal/platforms/bare-metal/utils/include -I/home/ubuntu/contents/ml-embedded-evaluation-kit/source/application/hal/platforms/bare-metal/images/include -I/home/ubuntu/contents/ml-embedded-evaluation-kit/source/application/hal/platforms/bare-metal/data_presentation/lcd/include -I/home/ubuntu/contents/ml-embedded-evaluation-kit/source/application/hal/platforms/bare-metal/timer/include -I/home/ubuntu/build/generated/bsp -I/home/ubuntu/contents/ml-embedded-evaluation-kit/dependencies/core-driver/include -I/home/ubuntu/contents/ml-embedded-evaluation-kit/dependencies/cmsis/CMSIS/DSP/Include -I/home/ubuntu/contents/ml-embedded-evaluation-kit/dependencies/cmsis/CMSIS/Core/Include -I/home/ubuntu/contents/ml-embedded-evaluation-kit/dependencies/cmsis/Device/ARM/ARMCM55/Include -I/home/ubuntu/contents/ml-embedded-evaluation-kit/dependencies/cmsis/Device/ARM/ARMCM55/Include/Template  -DARM_NPU=1 -DMPS3_PLATFORM=1 -DLOG_LEVEL=LOG_LEVEL_INFO -DACTIVATION_BUF_SRAM_SZ=0x00400000 -std=c++11 -g   -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -o CMakeFiles/ethos-u-test.dir/source/main.cpp.obj -c /home/ubuntu/contents/ml-embedded-evaluation-kit/source/main.cpp -H
```